# Prevent UIWebView sliding off the screen (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a full screen UIWebView component on the screen with fixed size content, so no scrolling required. When I nudge the screen the content in moving up or down.

The same effect can one experience all over the iPhone when there is a scroll-enabled component.

I would like to prevent this happening in my application. Please shed some light...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a javascript that prevents scrolling while keeping the ability to click on links:

```
document.onload = function(){
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
};
```

I have not tested this and can't find any documentation. I consider it a hack.

Comment: Thank you!
This one worked even using only the ontouchmove event handler.

I put this in the header of the HTML code:
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

is more correct :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need links to work:

```
myUIWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```